# Using compareTo in an Enum

Tags: java, enums, compareto

I have seen this code, an am unsure how it works with the compareTo.
Could someone guide me through how it works?

```
public enum Test
{
    POTATO("Potato"), 
    TOMATO("Tomato"), 
    CARROT("Carrot")

    public String Name;

    private Test(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public boolean testFor(Test t)
    {
        if (compareTo(t) <= 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Read [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/enum_compareto.htm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enum values are compared by the order they are created. So `POTATO` is less than `CARROT` because the ordinal is less for `POTATO` than for `CARROT`.

A few examples:

```
Test.POTATO.compareTo(Test.TOMATO); // returns -1, is less
Test.POTATO.compareTo(Test.POTATO); // returns 0, is equal
Test.CARROT.compareTo(Test.POTATO); // returns 2, is bigger
```

Comment: Those examples that you have, do they have to be in the Enum, or can they be in any Class?

Comment: You can call them from any class, as long as you import `Test`. If you want to use `compareTo(T)` in another class you have to implement the `Comparable` interface. It lets you specify a natural ordering for the class. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Answer (score 0):

**compareTo** is the final method from the **Enum** abstract class. According to this [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html,)

**compareTo(E o)** : *Compares this enum with the specified object for order.*